# NSAttributedString to HTML to NSAttributedString

Tags: html, swift, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

There are a lot of question like this but I have a weird problem. Here is the code:

```
let mutAttText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.textView.attributedText)
        let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
        ]
        var data: NSData = NSData()
        do {
        data = try mutAttText.dataFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, mutAttText.length), documentAttributes: attributedOptions)
        } catch {

        }

        let htmlString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(htmlString)
        do {
            let attrStr = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
            self.textView.attributedText = attrStr
        }
        catch {
            print("error creating attributed string")
        }
```

When I call it for the first time everything looks OK, but each next time font grows. Here is a bit from an output from htmlString(in code is print):

First call:

```
<style type="text/css">
 p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 15.0px '.SF UI Text';          color: #ffffff; background-color: #555555}

 span.s1 {font-family: '.SFUIText-Regular'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt}
```

Second call:

```
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 25.0px; font: 20.0px '.SF UI Text'; color: #ffffff; -webkit-text-stroke: #ffffff; background-color: #555555}

span.s1 {font-family: '.SFUIText-Regular'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 20.00pt; font-kerning: none}
```

I'm getting mad with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML to NSAttributedString and NSAttributedString to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441486/html-to-nsattributedstring-and-nsattributedstring-to-html)