# HTML to attributed string to HTML increase font size for random text

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

This is my HTML sample string.

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\"><title></title><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Cocoa HTML Writer\"><style type=\"text/css\">p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 40.0px; font: 33.2px '.SF UI Text'; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}span.s1 {font-family: '.SFUIText'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 33.19pt; font-kerning: none}</style></head><body><p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">123</span></p></body></html>"
```

Here are two functions to converting from HTML to attribute string to HTML for dealing server size too.

Attribute string to HTML:

```
func attributeToHTML(_ attr: NSAttributedString) -> String {

    var resultHtmlText = ""
    do {

        let r = NSRange(location: 0, length: (attr.length))
        let att = [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
        let d = try attr.data(from: r, documentAttributes: att)

        if let h = String(data: d, encoding: .utf8) {
            resultHtmlText = h
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("utterly failed to convert to html!!! \n>\(String(describing: attr))<\n")
    }
    return resultHtmlText
}
```

HTML to Attributed string:

```
func htmlToAttribute(_ string: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let htmlString = string
    var result = NSAttributedString()
    do {
        let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
        let str = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
        result = attributedString
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return result
}
```

When I convert HTML string to attributed string it increases the font size, and working perfect with attributed string to HTML conversion.

**By enumerating objects I can edit font size too, but its dynamic content any type of HTML string get in response. So this is not solutions.**

Please suggest the way how to deal with HTML content in UITextview for editing and storing in server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992950/ios7-font-size-change-when-create-nsattributedstring-from-html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590184/swift-font-size-increases-when-converting-html-string-to-attributed-string-and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441486/html-to-nsattributedstring-and-nsattributedstring-to-html ?

Comment: I already mentioned, 
By enumerating objects I can edit font size too, but its dynamic content any type of HTML string get in response. So this is not solutions.

Comment: It's explained that there seems to be a bug: " I don´t know why he is convert px to pt". It seems to be on Cocoa(Touch), so there shouldn't be a lot you can do except modify them.