# NSAttributedString to HTML objective-c

Tags: html, objective-c, macos, nsattributedstring, nspasteboard

i am getting the `NSAttributedString` from some applications with the help of `NSPasteboard` (when someone copy). The font in the `NSAttributedString` is always good but sometimes (depending on the application), when i convert to HTML, i get a different font and size. For example : Calibri goes to Helvetica. Here is my code :

```
  //Get pasteboard nsattributedstring
   NSArray *classes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSAttributedString class], nil];
   NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
   BOOL ok = [pasteboard canReadObjectForClasses:classes options:options];
   if(ok){
       NSArray *copiedItems = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];
       if (copiedItems != nil) {
           NSAttributedString *stringTest = [copiedItems lastObject];
           NSDictionary *documentAttributes = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
           NSData *htmlData = [stringTest dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, stringTest.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
           htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       }
   }
```

I get my `NSAttributedString` from the pasteboard which is fine, then i convert it to HTML. It is when i convert it to HTML the problem, it changes the font. For example, i use Calibri, MacOS doesn't have this font so it won't work.

**This is on MacOS

Comment: Regarding the size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560409/html-to-attributed-string-to-html-increase-font-size-for-random-text

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the font isn’t available?

Comment: I know, looking for a solution for that. Even if Calibri doesn't exist in mac, the NSAttributedString still writes Calibri but the conversion to HTML transforms it to Helvetica. I also got different results in google docs for safari and chrome which is strange.

Comment: I came across something like this and was able to use my desired font by adding the font as attribute to the Attributed String, have you tried it?

Comment: Hey thanks, even if you don't have the font it works? For example Calibri is not there on macos, the attributedstring is saying Helvetica instead. Ill try adding the NSFont attribute Calibri.

Comment: When adding a font attribute, i get a nil error because it doesn't know anything about Calibri.