# Converting from HTML to NSAttributedString wrong attributes

Tags: html, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to save a `NSAttributedString` to the server, and when i need it, get it back with all the attributes

After a hour of searching, I've found this code

```
extension NSAttributedString {
var toHTML: String {
    let documentAttributes = [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
    do {
        let htmlData = try self.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length), documentAttributes:documentAttributes)
        if let htmlString = String(data:htmlData, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8) {
            return htmlString
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("error creating HTML from Attributed String")
        return ""
    }
    return ""
}

extension String {
var fromHTML: NSAttributedString {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}
```

When i need to transform a `NSAttributedString` to HTML format, it does it right

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\">\n<title></title>\n<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Cocoa HTML Writer\">\n<style type=\"text/css\">\np.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 20.0px Palatino}\nspan.s1 {font-family: \'Palatino\'; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 20.00pt}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">Hello world</span></p>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

But when I'm trying to format it back to `NSAttributedString`, it changes the actual size of the font

```
Hello world{
NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 ";
NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x121d04440> font-family: \"Palatino\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 26.67pt";
NSKern = 0;
NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 31/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
NSStrokeColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 ";
NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?.

Comment: It's because there is an issue with NSAttributedString & HTML Code conversion in CocoaTouch (and maybe Cocoa). It seems that it misuse pt & px for font sizes. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441486/html-to-nsattributedstring-and-nsattributedstring-to-html

Comment: Quite awful, i hope it will get fixed sometimes.
The thread @Larme linked seems to work. Thanks :3